# Is it possible to use Firestore and nodemailer to send an email dependent on document data validation content?

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, nodemailer

I would like to send an email using the .onCreate method but only on condition if a field in the document is equal to "public"

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    // Allow the user to read data if the document has the 'visibility'
    // field set to 'public'
    match /cities/{city} {
      allow read: if resource.data.visibility == 'public';
    }
  }
}
```

How is this incorporated  with the  sendMail function.

```
exports.sendMail = functions.firestore.document('Companys/{companyid}/Post-Operation/{postoperationid}').onCreate((snap, context) => {
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the official documentation you can use

[Trigger Email](https://firebase.google.com/products/extensions/firestore-send-email)

to composes and sends an email based on the **contents** of a document written to a specified Cloud Firestore collection.

Please consider that to install and use Firebase extensions, your project must be on the Blaze plan